# The apple spawn inside the snake

Tags: python, pygame

i'm making a game and i found something that annoys me. The apple spawning inside a snake. i defined the snake head(sh) which is the only function that interact with the apple. Not the other parts of the snake. So, how do you make this not happen?

i tried using [Pygame Snake - Apple spawning inside snake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429340/pygame-snake-apple-spawning-inside-snake) and edit it to make it work. And i tried making a if statement on the pygame rectangle collide code.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*
import cv2
import time
import random
import pickle
import shutil
import OpenGL

dw = 1280
dh = 720 
at = 40
bs = 20
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((dw, dh))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    menu(1)
        screen.fill(white)
        mts("Paused", black, -100, 100)
        mts("Press esc to go back to the game or press space to go back to the menu", black, 25, 45)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

#define the apple to spawn in a random place
def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, dw-at, bs)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, dh-at, bs)

    return randAppleX,randAppleY

def snake(bs, sl):
    for XnY in sl:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Dgreen, [XnY[0],XnY[1],bs,bs])

def gameLoop():
    global at
    global bs
    hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    gameHack = False
    Speed = 20
    lead_x = dw/2
    lead_y = dh/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'music1.ogg'))
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

    slist = []
    sl = 0
    if sl > 2304:
        gameHack = True

    randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Game over", red, -50,100)
            mts("Press enter to play again or press space to go back to the menu", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        gameExit = False
                        gameOver = False
                        menu(1)
        while gameHack == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Hacked", red, -50,100)
            mts("You hacked or exploit the game, press enter to quit the game", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and lead_x_change != bs:
                    lead_x_change = -bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and lead_x_change != -bs:
                    lead_x_change = bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and lead_y_change != bs:
                    lead_y_change = -bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and lead_y_change != -bs:
                    lead_y_change = bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and Speed >= 10 and Speed < 60:
                    Speed += 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and Speed <= 60 and Speed > 10:
                    Speed -= 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)

        if not pygame.Rect(0, 0, dw, dh).contains(lead_x, lead_y, bs, bs):
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        screen.fill(white)

        #draw the apple
        apple = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,at,at])

        sh = []
        sh.append(lead_x)
        sh.append(lead_y)
        slist.append(sh)
        snake(bs, slist)

        if len(slist) > sl:
            del slist[0]

        for eachSegment in slist[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == sh:
                gameOver = True

        score(sl)
        highscore(hs)

        if sl > hs:
            hs += 1
            os.remove( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN') )
            pickle.dump( sl, open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "wb" ) )
            hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )


        pygame.display.update()

        #make the apple spawn
        if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + at or lead_x + bs > randAppleX and lead_x + bs < randAppleX + at:
            if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1
            elif lead_y + bs > randAppleY and lead_y + bs < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1


        clock.tick(Speed)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

i expected it to not spawn in the snake, but it did.

Comment: did you create the same question again ? Why. Why did you delete previous question?

Comment: create minimal working example with your problem - this code doesn't run.

Comment: always add tag `python` and code will be colored - it makes code more readable.

Comment: i did the same question to repost it. I thought your answer worked but after a few more plays it didn't work.

Comment: so you should describe it in question and maybe it could help to resolve it. Now you only waste our time. Someone else may give the same answer as mine and he will waste only time. It is good to give us as much information as it is possible - not delete information.

Comment: i gave more information

Comment: you only add link to deleted question - but other people can't see deleted question.

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area which is covered by the apple is greater than an part of the snake.
You've to use [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) th verify if the snake is in the area of the apple:

```py
appleRect = pygame.Rect(randAppleX, randAppleY, at, at)
if appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y):
    # [...]
```

The snake consists of the *head* **and** a list of *body* part. If a new random position for an apple is generated, then you've to verify if the apple does **not** cover the *head* **and not** [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) part of the *body*:

```py
if not appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) and \
   not any(appleRect.collidepoint(*p) for p in slist):
    # [...]
```

The code to spawn a new apple may look like this:

```py
appleRect = pygame.Rect(randAppleX, randAppleY, at, at)
if appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y):
    while True:
        randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
        appleRect = pygame.Rect(randAppleX, randAppleY, at, at)
        if not appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) and \
           not any(appleRect.collidepoint(*p) for p in slist):
            break
    sl += 1
```